# How to calculate variance of min. of N random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random, estimation

I have a realized dataset of random sample Y1 + Y2 ... + Yn from Exp($\lambda$) distribution. I want to estimate: $\mu$ = 1/$\lambda$

T = n * P where P is min for (Y1, Y2 ... , Yn) and is unbiased estimator for $\mu$ = 1/$\lambda$

How can I calculate Var(T) that is needed to calculate MSE(T)?

Comment: 'Y1+Y2+...+Yn'  should be 'Y1,Y2,...Yn'. Why are you adding them up? So for variance of $T=n\min (Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$, find out first the distribution of $\min(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom That is where I am stuck at.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables